# Elements overlapping each other when resizing the window

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a header section in a website which consists of:

- Logo
- Login, Register buttons
- Menu
- Language picker

And I want to make them in a single row, but the problem is that they overlap each other when I am resizing the window, specifically the login button overlaps the logo and the language picker overlaps the main menu.

```
<div id="header-container" class="container">
  <div id="header-container-nav" class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-3">LOGO</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">LOGIN BUTTONS</div>
    <div class="col-md-5">MENU</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">LANGUAGE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using bootstrap here, I would use `flex`

I'd use this **HTML**

```
  <div id="header-container-nav">
    <div">LOGO</div>
    <div>LOGIN BUTTONS</div>
    <div>MENU</div>
    <div>LANGUAGE</div>
  </div>
```

and this **CSS**

```
#header-container-nav {
  display: flex;
}
```

And now you can adjust the size of each item (check out this article http://javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css-flexbox2.shtml)

Comment: yah but I want the elements to go into a column when they are resized.

Comment: You can use a media query and then change the flex direction

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. I did solve my problem with a combination of a bootstrap and this. Oh never mind this doesn't work on IE properly :(

Comment: What IE version are you trying to check?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I was checking IE 11.